# Do Challenge battles use the same player pool?

Tags: clash-royale

At this time, there are two types of Challenge battles: Grand and Classic, the only difference being the rewards issued to the player.

Given that participation in Challenge battles is lower than general battles (considering the entry fee), and that true inter-match-communication is non-existent, is it possible that players in Challenge matches are drawn out of a general Challenge pool, rather than a Challenge-classification-specific pool?

Can a low-stakes Classic player unknowingly get matched up to a high-stakes Grand player for a Challenge battle, or are player pools for Challenge matches separated by Challenge type?

Comment: Didn't found any good source to post answer but from my personal experience there are two player pools. In classic challenge I usually get to 8-9 wins with no problem but in grand challenge I hardly get 5 wins.
[Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClashRoyale/comments/55hiay/grand_and_classic_challenge_player_pool/) on what I was talking about.

Comment: When sharing a match, it specifies what type of match it was. If they had the same player pool, the "match type indicator" would not be consistent among the two accounts, thus proving (?) they can't be the same.